# Django REST framework Query Throughput on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, twitch

I've trying to run a simple django server on amazon lightsail.

The server is supposed to be a backend that serves game state to twitch viewers via an extension.  I'm currently trying to have each viewer poll my backend every second.

Trying a very bear bones read to start I'm essentially storing the game state in memory using django's cache (there's only one tracked 'player' for now) and serving it back to users via the django REST framework.

Given that my requests and responses are quite small I'd expect to easily serve at least a few hundred users but I seem to top out of the sustainable CPU usage at around 50 users.  Is this expected for this setup?  Are there optimizations I can make or obvious bottlenecks?

Here's my backend that gets polled every second (I update settings post-git pull to debug=False and update the databse settings)

https://github.com/boardengineer/extension

Normal backend reads come in at about 800 bytes.

I tried returning empty responses to test if the response size should be optimized but it only made a small difference.

I thought of removing header content to further reduce response size but I don't think i found a way to do so correctly.

I also tried removing some of my middleware hoping to make the server more lean but I failed to find any middleware to remove

Comment: You have DEBUG=True in your settings, what command are you using to run server? gunicorn uvirorn or runserver?

Comment: What size Lightsail instance? Specifically, how many CPU cores? And are  you running `gunicorn` or similar configured to take advantage of all the available CPU cores? Are you aware all Lightsail instances are burst instances? Burst instances are not meant to support sustained CPU load for very long. Once you run out of burst credits on  the instance the server will become unresponsive for a while.

Comment: I disable debug after I pull.

I'm using basically the smallest size lightsail instance its 1 vcpu.  Running with whatever bitnami apache setup aws uses by default.  I run the server by restarting apache.

is lightsail not intended for use case that basically maintain low sustained cpu load?  I thought if i stayed under 10% usage most of the time I'd be good.